# Linux : Search for a particular word in all the files

Tags: linux, grep

I am using Ubuntu 12 .
I am trying to search for the word "SymbolSetThree" in my Ubuntu Machine home directory .

For this i used

```
 grep "SymbolSetThree" /home
```

**It simply displayed as grep: /home: Is a directory**

**Please let me know how to search for a particular word in all the files in Linux ??**

This is what i tried

```
sai@sai-Aspire-4720Z:/$  grep "SymbolSetThree" /home
grep: /home: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 6):

You are close, you just need the `-r` switch to have your command working properly.

```
 grep -r "SymbolSetThree" /home
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find:

```
find /home -type f | xargs grep SymbolSetThree
```

The same result can be achieved by using the `-exec` argument to `find` (instead of `xargs`).

Comment: This is what I find perplexing when working in Linux. There is no standard format for placing arguments/options/location(path). Tough to remember when location comes before options, etc. While I too use this find command at times, why would one use this when the grep -r achieves the same thing in one step and is less verbose and is meant for searching with files ?

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of tasks I really like ack-grep, is programmer oriented (only source files, .py .rb .c .sh) but with -a it looks for all kind of files.

```
ack-grep -a "SymbolSetThree"
```

Comment: The name of the program is "ack", not "ack-grep", although there are many packagers who call it "ack-grep" because of a naming conflict.  The ack home page is at http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: Well, in Ubuntu which is what OP is running is ack-grep because of a name conflict with another ack (Kanji code converter). I always define an alias back to ack for usability.

Comment: Hey, just did an ack --version and it seems you're the author, thanks @AndyLester, really nice tool.